# correct use of SQLiteOpenHelper (and some consultation)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following code below.

I am creating a database in my application that uses SQLiteOpenHelper.
I have couple of concerns and would appreciate some consults.
Direct answers for these were not found on stack overflow as they might be subjective.

1 - I will be using this database from several activities. However I am not planning on making this a singleton to avoid leaks, but rather I will be getting the getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase() inside each method. I plan on doing a db.close() inside each activity's onDestroy() .Is this advisable ? given my app has couple of activites and is not a huge app.

2 - I am not following and DAO model, nor I am using a different class for every table.
The way I see it, I don't need to. Do I ?

3 - (A question rather than consult)
In the code below, I am not creating a database of the form

```
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
```

So all the references to the database (from my activities) are being done via the methods in the same subclassed SQLiteOpenHelper, therefore I am referencing the physically created database directly via getWritableDatabase and getReadableDatabase.
Do I need to create an instance of SQLiteDatabase and use it ? Even inside the subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper ?

Below is the code.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDbName";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "myTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private Context ctx;

public DbHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.ctx = context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE myTable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    //nothing here now. maybe later.
}

public void insertTitle(String title)
{
    ContentValues titleCV = new ContentValues();
    titleCV .put("title", title);

        getWritableDatabase().insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, titleCV );
}

public void getTitles()
{
    Cursor result = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, title FROM myTable", null);

    while (result.moveToNext())
    {
        int id = result.getInt(0);
        String titleGotten= result.getString(1);
    }

    result.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Q1

If you have a scenario within your app that have two parallel threads accessing the database, use a single instance of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` (singleton or member in the `Application` or whatever). If not you don't need to.

about calling `db.close()`, if it is in the `onDestroy()`, then it's fine.

#### Q2

a DAO is an abstraction layer to ease maintaining and scaling your project. If you are not going to scale or maintain your code (upcoming releases or something), then I suppose you don't need one.

#### Q3

You don't need to create an instance of `SQLiteDatabse`. when you call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`, `SQLiteOpenHelper` creates and maintains an instance. The same instance is used the next time you call `getReadable\WritableDatabase()`.

let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: make a staic instace of SqliteOpenHelper 
step 2: you never close conexion to database, sqlite manage itself the sequencial access to write or read :)

`private static ControladorBBDD instancia;`

my class: `public class ControladorBBDD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {`

default :

```
private ControladorBBDD(Context ctx_p) throws Exception {   
super(ctx_p, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        try {
            ControladorBBDD.ctx = ctx_p;
            DB_PATH = ctx.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
            String myPath = DB_PATH;// + DB_NAME;
            this.createDataBase();

            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
            Conexiones.escribirLog(Log.getStackTraceString(ex),
                    ctx.getString(R.string.versionReal));
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

and my way to implement a conexion to database:

```
public static synchronized ControladorBBDD getBBDD(Context ctx_p)
            throws Exception {
        if (instancia == null) {
            instancia = new ControladorBBDD(ctx_p);
        }
        return instancia;
    }
```

and to call it from activities:

`dblectura = ControladorBBDD.getBBDD(getApplicationContext());`
where `private ControladorBBDD dblectura;`

i hope that it helps, important thing is that you use applicationContext, no Activity context ;))

Answer (score -2):

well if i were u i would create a class and the dbhelper as a subclass then i would use a open and a close function for main class and also the insert

```
whenever i want to use database i do it like this
mainclass mc=new mainclass(this);
mc.open();
mc.insert();
mc.close();
```

Comment: Do you open and close it every time?and what happens when you have multi-threads?

Comment: yes however i think for such cases if u use content provider and then cursorloader u will acheve the best possible thing i reccomond u to see the android content provider tutorial for bootcamp and i that this issue is fully covered.